# PHP MySQL how to associate two fields in one table row?

Tags: php, mysql

If I could talk to my database table, I would say "if client_id and salesrep_id are in the same row, do this!

Most of the conditional logic I've got. It's the "in the same row" part I'm struggling with.

Essentially, I'm building a system that allows all sales reps to view the entire data table but will permit each rep to update only their own specific entries.

The idea is to disable everybody else's "EDIT" links in the display.

Like so ...

```
    <?php if ($row_listClients['client_id'] && $row_listClients['salesrep_id']) { ?>
    <td><a href="edit_clients.php?client_id=<?php echo $row_listClients['client_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Obviously the initial condition doesn't work ( && will always be true ) but everything else works great. It's just this one bit I'm stuck on.

Hope that makes sense, I know it's probably pretty basic stuff.

Thanks a bunch guys, any pointers would be really appreciated.

--

Here's the query :

```
    $query_listClients = "SELECT client_id, user_id, repname, date, client_type, company,
    contact_firstname, contact_lastname, phone, email, property, address, city, province,
    repnotes FROM clientdata ORDER BY company ASC";
    $listClients = mysql_query($query_listClients, $connAdmin) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_listClients = mysql_fetch_assoc($listClients);
```

Thanks again ...

--

Sample of database data - which I entered as a test only. The first two number are client_id and user_id respectively:

```
    19;"33"; "Ronald Wharton"; "March 20 2013"; "Commercial"; "Bonkers Inc."; "Brett";
    "Bonkers"; "987   654 3211"; "brentbonkers@bonkersinc.com"; "Retail Outlet"; 
    "12765 34 Ave"; "Lost Soul City"; "Sask"; "Brett wants to meet with Keith and Dean 
    before the end of the week.  Please call before Friday."
```

Don't know if that's any help, but there ya go, thanks.

Comment: You should handle this in your SQL using a WHERE clause; you'll get a lot less SQL data to parse, and things will generally be much faster.  Show us your SQL, and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: and why is a && always true??

Comment: @ernie I think he wants to fetch them anyways just not show the edit link

Comment: I think the problem here is with your query, not your PHP.

Comment: i think you want `if($row_listClients['client_id'] == $row_listClients['salesrep_id'])`

Comment: if($row_listClients['client_id'] == $row_listClients['salesrep_id']) turns off all the links, tried it already. I will post the query.

Comment: @user1515259 if everything turns into a plain edit link, we might need to see a var_dump of $row_list as well, and/or a sample of your database data

Comment: as suggested by @ernie add a WHERE clause to your SQL so that you only get the rows where salesrep_id = x

Comment: The query uses "user_id"  ... I used salesrep_id in my question just to get the point across.  User_id is actually correct.  Just FYI, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reread your question.  It sounds as if you're querying to get all records, but only want to show edit links for items a particular sales rep should be allowed to edit.

Since you want all records, this shouldn't be done via SQL, and it sounds like all you need to do is change:

```
<?php if ($row_listClients['client_id'] && $row_listClients['salesrep_id']) { ?>
```

To something like:

```
<?php if ($row_listClients['salesrep_id'] == $currentSalesRepId) { ?>
```

You'll obviously need to use the appropriate variable for the `$currentSalesRepId`.

Comment: Thanks Ernie, Lucky Soni was on the right track too, his SESSION advice really paid off, both you guys rock!  Thanks again ...

Answer (score 1):

You should store the current salesrep_id (the one who is logged in) in a session and then compare it with the salesrep_id that is returned by mySql query (in the example below i have taken the current logged in salesrep_id equal to 1)

add a WHERE clause to your SQL statement like so:

`SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE salesrep_id = 1`

that you only get the rows where salesrep_id = 1

OR if you want to get all the rows from the database and then

`SELECT * FROM $tableName`

and then

// check if returned salesrep_id = current Sales Rep. Id (1 in this example)

`<?php if ($row_listClients['client_id'] && $row_listClients['salesrep_id'] == 1) : ?>`

// Show the edit link

`<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Same result as before, when I tried using == in place of &&. All the links lose their <a href> and turn into plain text. Ideally, only the other sales reps links will go blank, leaving the logged in user's links still active.  But, still, muchos gracias.

Comment: @user1515259 Yes you need to compare the two salesrep_id :)